# Is using wildcards in Ansible Collection 'ansible.controller' module 'export' possible?

Tags: rest, ansible, ansible-awx

We want to keep the configuration of two Ansible Automation Platform (AAP) v2 clusters in sync. For this we want to use the Ansible Collection `ansible.controller`. In a playbook, the `export` module should be used to selectively export e.g. `job_templates` and import them to the AAP test cluster using the `import` module. But only with templates that start with e.g. `LNX_`.

We've tried using `*` as a wildcard, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to use wildcards at this point, or another clever solution?

```yaml
  - name: "Get all from {{ vault_controller_host_prd_aap23 }}"
    export:
      controller_host:     "{{ vault_controller_host_prd_aap23 }}"
      validate_certs:       False
      controller_username: "{{ vault_controller_host_prd_aap23_username }}"
      controller_password: "{{ vault_controller_host_prd_aap23_password }}"
        projects:            "LNX*"
        job_templates:       "LNX*"
        credentials:         "LNX*"
      register: command_output
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you like to use [`export` module – export resources from Automation Platform Controller](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/awx/awx/export_module.html) in order to download the JSON definitions of `job_templates`.

> *Is there a way to use wildcards at this point?*

As far as I know, no. This is because the modules in question are just wrapper for the [Ansible Tower REST API](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html) and do not support a `?search=` parameter currently. You may also have a look into [`export.py`](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/awx_collection/plugins/modules/export.py) and [`import.py`](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/awx_collection/plugins/modules/import.py).

> *or another clever solution?*

You would need several tasks and multiple calls against the Controller. First [List Job Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73945548/6771046), second post-process or filter the result set, than, gather the Job Templates which have the properties in question.

Further reading which might help in this case, [How to schedule deletion of unused template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73319490/6771046)

---

An other option might be to use directly REST API calls via the `uri` module and as already described before but together with the `?search=LNX_` option

> *[**Searching**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_list) Use the search query string parameter to perform a case-insensitive search within all designated text fields of a model.*

```bash
# Test
curl --silent --user ${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD} https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/?search=LNX_ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n"
# Export
curl --silent --user ${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD} https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/?search=LNX_ | jq .
```

will result into the expected output, a wildcard will not be necessary.